# Unable to connect to presentation because of network issues in Lync 2013

Tags: office365, lync-2013

How do you determine the cause of "couldn't connect to the presentation because of network issues" in Lync 2013?  Is there a log file that I can examine? I don't have a firewall or proxy or VPN so I know it isn't any of those causing the connection to fail. It is bandwidth? I don't have any problems with TeamViewer on the same computer and internet connection.